# The coordinates of device screen doesn't correspond to the image displayed

Tags: java, android

In my app, an entire large jpg image (6000 x 5000 pixels) is displayed by imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imagePath));. 
A onTouch listener is set to the imageView. User should be able to tap the screen and leave a marker at the coordinates generated by the tapping.

The problem is that since the device being tested on is 800 x 1280, every time when a user taps on the screen, the marker appears in a small rectangular area in the top left corner of the image.

So my question is that if there is a way to get the coordinates on the image on tapping? If no how can I apply the screen coordinates to the image? It needs to be considered that the user might zoom the image to a certain size he/her likes.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
    imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri( imagePath));
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
                float x = motionEvent.getRawX();
                float y = motionEvent.getRawY();
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == 1)
                {
                    PointF pinPoint = new PointF(x , y);
                    if(imageView.isReady())
                    {
                        imageView.setPin(pinPoint);
                    }
                }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: In Android apss it's highly inefficient to load such a big bitmap in first place, you will likely obtain some memory issues. [See guideline about bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html).

Comment: If the whole image fits inside the view it means it's scaled to fit. So you can use getX() and getY() to get the tap coordinates relative to the view bounds. With those you can calculate the real image coordinates by doing something like `realX = motionEvent.getX() * ( realImageWidth / imageView.getWidth());`. Do the same for Y. It's also good to check what scale type does your imageView have so the whole image is on screen.